# HTML <picture> in bootstrap column selected by viewport width, not column width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm building a bootstrap two-column layout (10 + 2 wide) for main content and a sidebar. In the 10 column area, I am attempting to use the HTML `<picture>` element to show a different image based on the width of the **column**, *not* viewport. The pictures contain text & graph data and I am using 5 versions of the graph with various details omitted instead of shrinking the images.

[image]

Using the `min-width:` `media` tag selects the particular image based on the entire viewport window instead of the width of bootstrap's 10 column box. I need the image selected based on the 10-column width.

TIA

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
          <picture>
         <source media="(min-width: 964px)" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/RCVnxvd/Chemo-Adverse-Reactions-964x701.png">
      <source media="(min-width: 809px)" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/820HC9P/Chemo-Adverse-Reactions-809x701.png">
      <source media="(min-width: 532px)" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/HCdXHBX/Chemo-Adverse-Reactions-532x630.png">
      <source media="(min-width: 420px)" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/vsB3c8b/Chemo-Adverse-Reactions-420x630.png">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KNBfmhx/Chemo-Adverse-Reactions-298x630.png" class="img-fluid">
       </picture>
     </div>
     <div class="col-2">
       <p>Sidebar</p>
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/ddessert/pen/VwLLrBO)